# showLine property of scatter chart in ng2-charts is not working

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

The title pretty much sums it up. Even though I set the showLine property to true in the ChartConfiguration the dots are not connected with a line in the chart.

I tried with the following versions:

- "chart.js": "^4.2.1", and "ng2-charts": "^4.1.1",
- "chart.js": "~3.8.0", and "ng2-charts": "^3.0.0",

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-gus4a9-97hc3u

It seems to work with the original chart.js library.

Am I missing something?

Comment: If you look closely at the chart, you'll see the grid lines are interrupted where the line would be... it appears the line color is white for some reason. Add a `borderColor` property after the `showLine` property, e.g., `borderColor: '#048'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As kikon pointed out in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75901977/showline-property-of-scatter-chart-in-ng2-charts-is-not-working?noredirect=1#comment133890801_75901977), there was never actually a problem, just a styling issue.